# Laravel syntax error put closing tag '}' where it shouldn't be when creating a link

Tags: laravel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title></title>

</head>

<body>

    <ul>

        @foreach ($tasks as $task)

            <li> 

                <a href="/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">

                    {{ $task->body }}

                </a>

            </li> 
                    }

        @endforeach

    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

This is lesson episode 6 from Laracasts (beginner's section).  My code looks exactly like what's being shown on the instructor's screen but I get an extra `}` after each hyperlink.  It took me a while to figure out how he divided the views between folders too.  Some pretty good info but the instructor needs to slow down a bit.  I probably missed something here too but I've rewinded and rewatched at least 5 times now.

Comment: Is this the code in your view? If so, just remove the extra `}` - or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @hockeymonkey33 you don't need this extra } to close foreach, you closed it by endforeach

Comment: remove } after this closing tag </li>

Comment: Minus 3 is brutal for basically an error stemming from a real problem with my vision.  I guess those guys never had the experience of getting blurry vision and having to go buy eye glasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title></title>

</head>

<body>

<ul>

    @foreach ($tasks as $task)

        <li> 

            <a href="/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">

                {{ $task->body }}

            </a>

        </li> 


    @endforeach

</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Try this. You don't need `}` after closing tag

Comment: Hey thanks for the help.  I had trouble seeing the screen due to vision problems.